# iOS: Excluding Pod dependency during Archiving

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, archive

There's a third party dependency in our app, which is integrated via Cocoapods. We want to include this dependency only during the build/run action but want to exclude it for the archive action for all the build configurations.

Can anyone guide me here?

Answer (score 0):

You can include a dependency only for the Debug configuration(used for build/Run actions) like this:

```
target 'MyTarget' do
    pod 'aPodLibrary', :configurations => ['Debug']

end
```

If you have more Debug configurations you can include them in the above array, this way only when you perform the archive action (building with Release configuration) the pod library will be included.
In you code you might need to conditionally exclude code:

```
#if canImport(aPodLibrary)
#endif
```